# SQL database query distinction and grouping

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have a table with columns Name VARCHAR, Department VARCHAR, Gender VARCHAR, and Age DOUBLE.  With a single query, how can I return a result set that has the youngest man and woman in each department?  Assume all ages are unique.

ANSI SQL query preferred, but using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select a.Name, b.*
 from
   your_table as a
 inner join
 (select 
   Department, Gender, min(Age) as min_age
 from your_table
 group by Department, Gender) as b
 on 
   a.Department=b.Department AND
   a.Gender=b.Gender AND
   a.Age=b.min_age;
```

Comment: what happens if two people in same dept have the same gender and born on the same day?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - Hi, it won't , OP said Age is a double, and unique

Comment: assuming Age is unique sounds like rubbish to me....! Representing age as a double is a design mistake

Comment: OP might be using double to represent fraction of age e.g. .5 years old :-) .5 being 6 months.  But I guess age is better derived from Birthdate and compute the Age; Age is not an input, it's a computation

Comment: This was just an example..  Age could just as easily have been Height, and instead task would be to get the Tallest man and woman from each department.

Comment: @Ilike Anonymity - you should consider to change your schema as explain by @Mitch Wheat, it will make your life easier in long-run

Comment: @ajreal - No need, but thanks.  Youngest/oldest, tallest/shortest, it was the generic approach that needed to be answered (and was), not that specific example I created off the top of my head.